# Powershell scripting questions

Tags: powershell

I want to popup the output executed in powershell[This is sample output of my powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7dE9.jpg)

In the picture you can see the "GetDirectories is not reconized" error.

If the error condition is matched in powershell output means i want to make a popup display the error "GetDirectories is not reconized"

Please suggest the powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
try {

    GetDirectories
    
}
catch {
    if ($Error[1].CategoryInfo.Reason -eq 'CommandNotFoundException' -and $Error[1].CategoryInfo.TargetName -eq 'GetDirectories' ) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('GetDirectories is not reconized', 'Error', 0, [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Exclamation)
    }
}
```

that would do that specifitik thing and only in the given case

Answer (score 0):

```
Try {
        GetDirectories -ErrorAction Stop
    }



Catch {

        Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

        $ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OK
    
        $MessageboxTitle = "Test pop-up message title"
        $Messageboxbody = "GetDirectories is not reconized"
        $MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
    
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($Messageboxbody,$MessageboxTitle,$ButtonType,$messageicon)

     }
```